# Filter array by unique item in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, unique

I want filter list by unique item in sublist

example:

```py
#       ---------
#       v       v
lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]

# result
[[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

I am using, want:

```py
def setx0(arr):
   r = []
   filter(lambda x : r.append(x) if x[0] not in set(map(lambda x: x[0], r)) else False, arr)
   return r
```

a better way?

Comment: A nested for loop could be used for this. Would make it a bit more readable (and easier to debug without a debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for straight forward:

```
lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]

seen = set()
new_list = []

for ele in lst:
    if ele[0] not in seen:
        new_list.append(ele)
        seen.add(ele[0])

print new_list
```

Result:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list is already sorted, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby 
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> [next(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, itemgetter(0))] 
[[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the very efficient, but if you like one-liners:

```
try:
    reduce
except NameError:  # Python 3
    from functools import reduce

lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]

filtered = reduce(lambda a, b: a+[b] if b[0] not in set(x[0] for x in a) else a,
                  lst, [])
print(filtered)  # -> [[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With sorted list, the easiest would be

```
>>> lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> dict(reversed(lst)).items()
[(1, 0), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const lst = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
      foundItems = [],
      result = []

for (let i in lst) {
  const lstItem = lst[i]
  if (foundItems.indexOf(lstItem[0]) === -1) {
    foundItems.push(lstItem[0])
    result.push(lstItem)
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) // print [[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```